# How should look script that launches program on startup

Tags: debian, terminal, gnome, console

I want program `rescuetime` to be launched when computer loads.

I've found that for this task script should be created in `/etc/init.d/my_script`
and this lines to be entered to console

```
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/my_script
update-rc.d my_script defaults
```

What I can not figure is how this script should look. To launch program from terminal I simply enter `rescuetime`.

Comment: check how looks other init scripts, usually they have enough comments to be self-explained

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mess with init scripts.  In Debian, you can just add a line in `/etc/init.d/rc.local` that calls the program; it will then be run after all the init scripts.

If you call the program in `/etc/init.d/boot.local` instead, it will run only at boot, not when switching runlevels.